# Javascript image swap at mouseover - ugly highlighting effect?

Tags: javascript, image, mouseover, highlight, swap

I'm a **JavaScript newbie** working on a website and I've run into an issue that's beyond my ken to solve...

I made some picture links and have been researching the well-known *image swap on mouseover* JavaScript effect that can be found all over the web. I have some simple white image pics that I want to switch to blue when a user scrolls over them. I got bits of code from here and there and slowly pieced together a beginners understanding of the inner workings of what I'm trying to do. I threw together a quick *sandbox* html file with just the javascript code and you can see that [here](http://www.kendallfrancis.com/jsindex.html).

(Notice the script functioning without a problem)

Now when I migrated the working code into my homepage, everything seems alright except for ugly blue highlights that now appear around the links when the cursor is hovered over them

See here:

http://www.kendallfrancis.com/

I really want to fix this !

If you could help I'd be very, very grateful as most of my day has been spent in vain trying to figure this out - I need some expert perspective!

Here's my (bloated) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <title>Kendall Francis | Musician | Galactic Circus Diplodocus</title>
  <meta content="Kendall Francis" name="author">
  <meta content="Kendall Francis 1990-2011" name="copyright">
  <meta content="all" name="robots">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style type="text/css"><!-- @import "francis.css";--></style>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
if (document.images) {
   var mus1 = new Image();
   mus1.src = "images/music1.jpg";
   var mus2 = new Image();
   mus2.src = "images/music2.jpg";
}

function show_music() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["mus"].src = mus2.src;
  }
}

function hide_music() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["mus"].src = mus1.src;
  }
} 
//-->
<!--
if (document.images) {
   var pho1 = new Image();
   pho1.src = "images/photo1.jpg";
   var pho2 = new Image();
   pho2.src = "images/photo2.jpg";
}

function show_photo() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["pho"].src = pho2.src;
  }
}

function hide_photo() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["pho"].src = pho1.src;
  }
} 
//-->
<!--
if (document.images) {
   var vid1 = new Image();
   vid1.src = "images/video1.jpg";
   var vid2 = new Image();
   vid2.src = "images/video2.jpg";
}

function show_video() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["vid"].src = vid2.src;
  }
}

function hide_video() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["vid"].src = vid1.src;
  }
} 
//-->
<!--
if (document.images) {
   var who1 = new Image();
   who1.src = "images/who1.jpg";
   var who2 = new Image();
   who2.src = "images/who2.jpg";
}

function show_who() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["who"].src = who2.src;
  }
}

function hide_who() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["who"].src = who1.src;
  }
} 
//-->
</SCRIPT>       
</head>    
<body>
<div class="cenimg">
<img src="images/break.jpg" alt="kendallfrancis.com" title="Perpetual growth" width="424px" height="456px" class="imgcen"/>
</div>
<div>
   <div align="center">
    <a href="music.htm"
  onMouseOver="show_music(); return true" 
  onMouseOut="hide_music()">
<IMG SRC="images/music1.jpg" ALT="Kendall's music" title="Kendall's music" 
  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="40" name="mus" border=0></a>
  <img src="images/duck.jpg" title="What the duck?" alt="What the duck?" width="45px" height="40px">
  <a href="photo.htm"
  onMouseOver="show_photo(); return true" 
  onMouseOut="hide_photo()">
<IMG SRC="images/photo1.jpg" ALT="Kendall's photos" title="Kendall's photos"
  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="40" name="pho" border=0></a>      
  <img src="images/duck.jpg" alt="What the duck?" title="quack!" width="45px" height="40px">      
    <a href="video.htm"
  onMouseOver="show_video(); return true" 
  onMouseOut="hide_video()">
<IMG SRC="images/video1.jpg" ALT="Kendall's videos" title="Kendall's videos"
  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="40" name="vid" border=0></a>          
  <img src="images/duck.jpg" title="You're despicable!" alt="What the duck?" width="45px" height="40px">          
      <a href="who.htm"
  onMouseOver="show_who(); return true" 
  onMouseOut="hide_who()">
<IMG SRC="images/who1.jpg" ALT="Who is this guy?" title="Who is this guy?" 
  WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="40" name="who" border=0></a>      
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Also, if you have any tips on how I can cut down on the amount of code (I read something about function with arguments, or something... but didn't really understand it) er... yeah as you can tell I'm a real amateur.... But I'm real willing to learn if you're willing to bear with me!

Oh, and I did search for this before hand --- a lot --- could not find anything applicable. But, my apologies if you know this has been answered before.

Comment: Well those ugly highlights dint show up for me.Which browser were you checking in ?

Comment: it's in the image. open it in an image editor and fix it.

Comment: @Insomnolence Please see the updated script I posted

Comment: @ Clyde Lobo - checked in Firefox
@ Willem van Gennip - no sorry the images are both totally black in the background. Kindly check the first link I posted :) 
@mplungjan - thankyou, will do

Comment: Oh man, talk about confused.... @Willem van Gennip - I actually owe YOU an apology

Comment: css sprites are a better idea than image preloading : see http://webdesignandsuch.com/css-sprites-image-replacement/ for an example and explanation

Comment: @Willem van Gennip - cheers! looks very interesting. I think I'll definitely implement this approach when I get some time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those highlights are in the over-image themselves - the background is not totally black

Here is the shorter code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Kendall Francis | Musician | Galactic Circus Diplodocus</title>
  <meta content="Kendall Francis" name="author">
  <meta content="Kendall Francis 1990-2011" name="copyright">
  <meta content="all" name="robots">
  <style type="text/css"><!-- @import "francis.css";--></style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // an object containing one member per image 
  // with the corresponding images in an array
  var links = {
    "music":  ["images/music1.jpg","images/music2.jpg"],
    "photo":  ["images/photo1.jpg","images/photo2.jpg"],
    "video":  ["images/video1.jpg","images/video2.jpg"],
    "who"  :  ["images/who1.jpg",  "images/who2.jpg"]
  } // note: no comma after the last entry

  // preload
  for (var o in links) {
    links[o].images = []; // create an array
    for (var i=0;i<links[o].length;i++) { // only two images but could be more
      links[o].images[i]=new Image();
      links[o].images[i].src=links[o][i];
    }
  }

function show(img,idx) { 
  // pass the name of the image, which is also the key to the links object
  // the idx is 1 for over and 0 for out
  document[img].src = links[img].images[idx].src; 
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="cenimg">
<img src="images/break.jpg" alt="kendallfrancis.com" title="Perpetual growth" width="424px" height="456px" class="imgcen"/>
</div>
<div>

   <div align="center">

    <a href="music.htm"
  onMouseOver="show('music',1); return true" 
  onMouseOut="show('music',0); return true"><img 
  src="images/music1.jpg" alt="Kendall's music" title="Kendall's music" width="200" height="40" name="music" border="0"></a>

  <img src="images/duck.jpg" title="What the duck?" alt="What the duck?" width="45px" height="40px">

  <a href="photo.htm"
  onMouseOver="show('photo',1); return true" 
  onMouseOut="show('photo',0)"><img 
  src="images/photo1.jpg" alt="Kendall's photos" title="Kendall's photos" width="200" height="40" name="photo" border="0"></a>

  <img src="images/duck.jpg" alt="What the duck?" title="quack!" width="45px" height="40px">

    <a href="video.htm"
  onMouseOver="show('video',1); return true" 
  onMouseOut="show('video',0)"><img 
  src="images/video1.jpg" alt="Kendall's videos" title="Kendall's videos" width="200" height="40" name="video" border="0"></a>

  <img src="images/duck.jpg" title="You're despicable!" alt="What the duck?" width="45px" height="40px">

      <a href="who.htm"
  onMouseOver="show('who',1); return true" 
  onMouseOut="show('who',0)"><img 
  src="images/who1.jpg" ALT="Who is this guy?" title="Who is this guy?" width="200" height="40" name="who" border="0"></a>


</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: "please post a reason when you vote me down" -- Is that directed at me 'coz I didn't. Sorry if that don't make sense... new to this site and how it operates too

Comment: I owe you an apology, it was the images! But I was confused and inadvertently thought I had uploaded the correct ones. Now I'm making excuses. But that's why I said 'please look at the first link I provided' --- because I was certain it couldn't be them. It's a long story to explain what happened but it's how I went about creating and then exporting the images. I used GIMP and I got confused with which layer was what and then in a final fit of exasperation I opened up jpegs and colorised them while they were flattened --- it didn't click till now.

Comment: Thankyou for your help with the code -- I am going to compare what I wrote to what you have provided side by side tonight when I have a moment and hopefully nut out what you did. Also, I thought that there was no problem with the images (i.e. no highlighting) on the first link I provided because the background was white -- thus my conviction that it was a JavaScript problem not an image problem. Thanks again for your patience and I hope I didn't piss you off too much with my presumptuous arrogance.

Comment: No arrogance detected! Glad to help. And no, the comment about voting down was directed at whoever voted me down - I did not expect it to have been you anyway :) I'll add some comments to the code to clarify

Answer (score -1):

I beleive this to be a css problem..

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link_background

The link css properties causes the blue background to appear around a link

Comment: Nothing in the CSS gives the blue haze. It is the background of the mouseover image itself which is not black